# How can I make an input field and a button fill the entire row in a Bootstrap form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm trying to make the Post button stick to the right and the text field for the tags fill the entire left part of the row in the following Bootstrap 3 form:

[image: My lame form]

Here's the markup for the entire form:

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="entry" placeholder="Write something in Markdown..." rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" id="tags" placeholder="tag1, tag2, tag3...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Post</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I admittedly don't understand the Bootstrap grid system (or CSS in general) well enough to make this work - can you help me?

Comment: Using the grid system you're restricted to those columns. You could either make the Post button fill the full column by adding the `btn-block` to it, or you could look at using an input addon and having the input group 100% width (see [this link](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups)). The alternative would be to manually style the elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `.btn-block` class in your Post button to make it span the entire width of the column is on. In your case, `.col-sm-3`.

```
<div class="col-sm-3 text-right"> 
    <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" type="submit">Post</button>
</div>
```

Here you can see it. Note that I replaced the `.col-sm-*` classes with `.col-xs-*` ones, so you can see it directly.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<form>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea class="form-control" id="entry" placeholder="Write something in Markdown..." rows="3"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9">
            <input class="form-control input-sm" id="tags" placeholder="tag1, tag2, tag3...">
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-3 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm btn-block" type="submit">Post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think this is the real answer.

Answer (score 6):

You can do this:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


<div class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search for...">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Post</button>
  </span>
</div>
```

You can find more examples here: http://getbootstrap.com/components/#input-groups-buttons

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better. But is it possible to keep the input field and the button separate?

Comment: You need to set some `margin-left` on the button + change the `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-top-left-radius` to 1px. Can change this later if you need - have to go now sry ;)

Answer (score 3):

Fellow man, the bootstrap system uses a 12 grid system, try this:

```html
<div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="tag1, tag2, tag3...">
      <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Post</button>
      </span>
</div>
```

https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/

Comment: Thanks, this looks much better. But is it possible to keep the input field and the button separate?

Comment: Yes but thee will have to fiddle with le css files, fare thee well!

Comment: Well, my friend, then I will stick with thine original solution.

Answer (score 2):

Adding the `form-control` class to your `btn` element will make it fill its container.

`<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm form-control>Link Text</a>`

Text fields fill their container by default.

Comment: If you run into problems with vertical placement, wrap your `form-control` elements with `form-group` divs.

Answer (score 1):

```
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <textarea class="form-control" id="entry" placeholder="Write something in Markdown..." rows="3"></textarea>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-9">
      <input class="form-control input-sm" id="tags" placeholder="tag1, tag2, tag3...">
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-3 text-right">
      <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit">Post</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```